# matrix : generate a matrix from a set of nodes and number of links

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I have a set of nodes, and each node must have x links to other nodes.
(Sorry if i'm not using the correct terms, i'm not a native english)

My problem is to generate a graph that fulfill the above specification.

for example if my set of node/links required is this : 
(a,3)(b,1)(c,1)(d,1)(e,1)(f,3)

the graph should be

```
a------f
|\     |\
b c    d e
```

Can i get directions on how i can generate this type of graph, maybe enumerating graphs until i get one that answer the specification ... but that would be very bad.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: this looks like the problem of finding a graph from a 'degree sequence' - which is a fairly well known problem. However, your graphs have labelled nodes - is that important? In other words, if I swap the labels 'a' and 'b' in your graph, does it matter?

Comment: Ok, from your SO question it looks like it doesn't matter. Just use the Havel-Hakimi algorithm (remember to sort at each step) and that will give you a graph if one exists.

Comment: Thanks ! i'll look into it, and build my solution !